# How to create two columns of a dataframe from separate lines in a text file

Tags: python, pandas, text-files

I have a text file where  every other row either begins with "A" or "B" like this

```
A810 WE WILDWOOD DR
B20220901BROOKE
A6223 AMHERST BAY
B20221001SARAI
```

How can I read the text file and create a two column pandas dataframe where the line beginning with "A" is a column and likewise for the "B", on a single row.  Like this

```
|A                  |B              |
|:------------------|:--------------|
|A810 WE WILDWOOD DR|B20220901BROOKE|
|:------------------|---------------|
|A6223 AMHERST BAY  |B20221001SARAI |
|:------------------|---------------|
```

Comment: Is the A/B determining the order?

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this by using [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) :

```
from io import StringIO    
import pandas as pd

s = """A810 WE WILDWOOD DR
B20220901BROOKE
A6223 AMHERST BAY
B20221001SARAI
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=None, names=["A"])
#in your case, df = pd.read_csv("path_of_your_txtfile", header=None, names=["A"])

out = (
            df
              .join(df.shift(-1).rename(columns= {"A": "B"}))
              .iloc[::2]
              .reset_index(drop=True)
       )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
                     A                B
0  A810 WE WILDWOOD DR  B20220901BROOKE
1    A6223 AMHERST BAY   B20221001SARAI
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a `pivot`?

```
col = df[0].str.extract('(.)', expand=False)

out = (df
   .assign(col=col, idx=df.groupby(col).cumcount())
   .pivot(index='idx', columns='col', values=0)
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
                     A                B
0  A810 WE WILDWOOD DR  B20220901BROOKE
1    A6223 AMHERST BAY   B20221001SARAI
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which *only* works if the strings alternate, regularly, between `A` and `B`, as the OP states:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape((-1, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
```

Output:

```
                     A                B
0  A810 WE WILDWOOD DR  B20220901BROOKE
1    A6223 AMHERST BAY   B20221001SARAI
```